# How to make Owl Carusel slider looks like this

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to make my carusel looks like this slider on the picture.
The center image overlapping the two other images.
[image]

Comment: At least try to put some of your code

Comment: use with `Z-index & position` on css you will get the overlapping design.

Comment: @Bandi take a look now i've posted the code

Comment: @prasad  What kind of position should i use?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
stagePadding: 10,
loop:true,
margin:0,
nav:true,
responsive:{
    0:{
        items:1
    },
    600:{
        items:3
    },
    1000:{
        items:1
    },

    1200:{
      items:1
    }
}
})
```

and this is the html code

```
<div class="owl-carousel">
      <div class="item"><img src="img/slider1.png" alt="" /></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="img/slider1.png" alt="" /></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="img/slider1.png" alt="" /></div>
  </div>
```